# Cache-Control: expires_in does not change the headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cache-control

I have a Rails 3.2 app running on Nginx.

I need to set custom Cache-Control headers for one of the pages of my app.

I'm using `expires_in` - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/expires_in

```
def my_action
  expires_in 3600
```

When I open the page in development, though, the headers are:

`Cache-Control:must-revalidate, private, max-age=0`

I'm not resetting the headers anywhere else in the app. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: what is your rails version?

Comment: My rails version is 3.2

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
expires_in 2.hours, :public => true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try gem rails-cache_control. it will autotomiclly add Cache-Control header.